# Visual Studio 2010 - RemovePreviousVersions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Deployment Project with the following settings:

```
DetectNewerInstalledVersion = True
InstallAllUsers = True
RemovePreviousVersions = True
```

The project I am building has several DLLs that due to the legacy way that serialization was implemented the file versions for this project can not be incremented (which we are in the process of changing).

How can I get the setup project to remove the existing files entirely (or at least overwrite with all the new files)?

Maybe I need to script an uninstall in the installer (can someone link me to do this, I can't find)

I have looked around and for any existing questions and they all say "increment your file versions", however for me this is not currently an option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The setup project created with Visual Studio (2008 and 2010) will only replace files if the version number has been incremented. The obvious solution would be to just increment all version numbers; but as you said this is not feasible for you.

The behavior of the .msi file is basically determined by the moment when the [RemoveExistingProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371197.aspx) action is executed. Installers created with VS 2008 schedule this action *after* the new product has been installed. Modified assemblies whose version has not been incremented therefore don't get replaced. Some more details about the update behavior are described in this thread:

> [RemovePreviousVersions=True but previous version is not removed from the target machine](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/9ce5da29-3f37-4e7f-a548-1cbeb4a3e0a3)

To change the behavior, you can patch the created .msi file so that the [RemoveExistingProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371197.aspx) action is executed *before* the new product gets installed (this actually has been the behavior if you created the setup with Visual Studio 2005). Patching can e.g. be done using a small VBScript that runs as a post-built step:

```
Dim objInstaller
Dim objDatabase
Dim objView
Dim objResult

Dim strPathMsi 

If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 1 Then
    WScript.Echo "Usage: cscript fixRemovePreviousVersions.vbs <path to MSI>"
    WScript.Quit -1
End If

strPathMsi = WScript.Arguments(0)

Set objInstaller = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set objDatabase = objInstaller.OpenDatabase(strPathMsi, 1)
Set objView = objDatabase.OpenView("UPDATE InstallExecuteSequence SET Sequence=1450 WHERE Action='RemoveExistingProducts'")

WScript.Echo "Patching install sequence: UPDATE InstallExecuteSequence SET Sequence=1450 WHERE Action='RemoveExistingProducts'"
objView.Execute
objDatabase.Commit

WScript.Quit 0
```

Comment: That's awesome thanks. For others reference my PostBuildEvent is (save the vbs to the setup project directory): cscript $(ProjectDir)fixRemovePreviousVersions.vbs $(BuiltOuputPath)

Comment: @Seph how did you add a PostBuildEvent for an MSI project?

Comment: Ok I've found it, hidden away in the Properties window of the project. :)

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue with couple of setups migrated form 2005 t0 2010.
Edited setup (.msi) file with ORCA and changed the Execute Sequence.
RemoveExistingProducts before InstallInitialize
This has resolved the installation issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to perform a complete uninstall before a new installation is to

1. go to your "startup project", right-click and select "options".
2. Click on the "assembly information" button. Then increment the "assembly version" and the "file version" values, click "ok".
3. Then go to your setup project. Ensure that "`DetectNewInstalledVersion`" is set to true, "`RemovePreviousVersion`" is true, then increment "version" e.g from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1, and then a dialog box will appear asking you to update your "ProductCode", just select "yes". Make sure you "rebuild" your startup project and then rebuild your setup project.

This will do the trick. Enjoy. Then "right click" on your setup folder and choose "open folder in windows explorer" and look under the "release" folder.

Comment: Cannot increment version as mentioned in the OP: `due to the legacy way that serialization was implemented the file versions for this project can not be incremented`